# Excluding specific dependency from dependency in app

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

Suppose you have a python 2.7 application that requires **dependency A**, and **dependency A** requires **dependency B**. When adding **dependency A** to your python application it turns out that **dependency B** throws an error related to being only python 3 compatible and one can't upgrade the python application to 3.4 at this time.

What are the best solutions when it comes to this problem. **dependency A** is needed in the python application, but the small part that I need it for  **dependency B** is not relevant and not needed. All of these applications have a setup.py file in their root, so maybe `extras_require` could be relevant? For me it would be easiest to make an update in the python application and/or **dependency A**, since I would have to fork dependency B, since its a third party dep.

Anyone know how to do this?